# Secure Connection from Unity to Database

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

At the moment Unity connects to my database using the WWW class which then uses PHP to connect to my database. All the information from PHP to the database is encrypted, however, the connection between Unity and PHP is not encrypted allowing for a hacker to interrupt. Has anyone tried encrypting the connection from Unity to PHP before? If so, how would I go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to secure your internet endpoint, best way is using HTTPS. Get a certificate for free using [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).